# How to determine which javascript line causes the error when executing window.execScript in a BHO?

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer, com, bho

My question is general I am not looking for solve a specific error (I have a bunch of them :-)

My BHO is functional, `OnDocumentComplete` called. In `OnDocumentComplete` I can execute `window.execSrcipt("console.log('Hello');");` etc it works.

I also can run more complex 100 lines of scripts reading them from a stream to the string parameter of execScript method.

My question is: If any script error occurs (*any*) the COM exception does not contain the original javascript error info, for example the line number. 
I've tried to debug the BHO project (it's a C# class lib) and I also tried to use F12 Dev Tools in IE. In the IE console the red error is always the first line of the downloaded html so obviously IE can's catch correctly the injected script context, and the COM exception has no detailed info.

Now how can I get closer info?